# Can I determine whether a specific setting has changed in my application?

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, properties, settings

It's been my first time programming with View Models and so far, I have to say that I'm loving it! My current project saves a lot of user settings (using Properties.Settings), some of which are directly tied to the application's appearance at runtime. I've been using the following syntax so far:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += async (sender, e) =>
{
      // Some async design updates
}
```

As you can see, this event fires each time *any* setting changes, which I'm scared will lag my project as a *lot* of setting changes will be going on! I was wondering if there was any way for such an event to target a specific user setting?

Thanks!

Comment: the eventarts contains the property name. You can filter using that so that for non-required property you don't invoke the business logic.

Comment: @user1672994 Thank you! How could I not realise the answer was right in front of me!